# Can't create and insert data into a table in SQLite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, auto-increment, create-table

I pasted three SQLite files into `D:/Server/sqlite` of my Windows-based local Apache server, opened `sqlite3` and created `test.sqlite` by `.open --new test.sqlite`.

I'm trying to create a table and insert data by the following PHP code :

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:D:\Server\sqlite\test.sqlite');

$pdo->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablename` (`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL)');

$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Test')");
$insert->execute();
$pdo->lastInsertId();
```

But I get the error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on
> bool

And `test.sqlite` is still empty. What's wrong? With MySQL this works fine.

Comment: Basically: You should be [checking for PDO errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Comment: The table probably already exists but has different columns. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` leaves the old table definition there.

Comment: @Barmar As I mentioned, the file `test.sqlite` is empty, so it has no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CREATE TABLE` statement is invalid, so the table is not created, which means that the `INSERT` statement fails.

The correct syntax to define an integer autoincremented column in SQLite is:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

or:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

The differences with your code are:

- the use of the data type `INTEGER` (anything else will throw an error when used in conjunction with the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` or if that is missing it will not create an autoincremented column)
- the use of the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` (and not `AUTO_INCREMENT`
  which works in MySql) after the keywords `PRIMARY KEY`

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Y3Ajimz).